# Set text for a single item of a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, textview

I need to set a single title for each element of my Recycler view. How can I perform it?

This is my java code:

```
public class HorizontalAdapterViewTopDieci extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalAdapterViewTopDieci.HorizontalViewHolder>
{

private int[] items;

public HorizontalAdapterViewTopDieci(int[] items) {

    this.items = items;

}

@Override
public HorizontalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout_recycler_view_top_10, parent, false);
    return new HorizontalViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HorizontalViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.image.setImageResource(items[position]);
    holder.titleText.setText("Recipe");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.length;
}

public class HorizontalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView titleText;

    public HorizontalViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_ricette_categorie_primi_top_10);
        titleText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);

    }
} }
```

I also create the xml layout for the items (in this case images):

```
<LinearLayout

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:orientation="vertical"

>

<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/image_view_ricette_categorie_primi_top_10"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/test_pizza"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"


    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@color/colorRicette"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to add a text view here , aligned and centered but how can I after set this text ?

UPDATE : this is your solution ankit but what is wrong?

Comment: Please attach also the HorizontalAdapterImageViewTopDieci class. You should add a TextView to your xml layout and set the text programmatically in the Adapter.

Comment: @gabodroid here you are

Comment: Your array only has drawables. What text you want to show in each row?

Comment: Do you want to show text on imageview?

Comment: I need to show a String for example : "Image 1"

Comment: @Bek I need to show the text below each image, aligned and centered

Comment: can you share your  item_layout_recycler_view_immagini_top_10.xml file

Comment: @Bek done, just now

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial https://www.android-examples.com/android-recyclerview-listview-with-imageview-textview-json/

Comment: make your linear layout orientation vertical and add textview below imageview and settext to it inside your adapter just like you did with imageview

Comment: @Bek mean you inside the Adapter class or inside ActivityMain?

Comment: HorizontalAdapterImageViewTopDieci

Comment: @Bek I will try

Answer (score 1):

Create single item xml as :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:orientation="vertical"

>



<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/image_view_ricette_categorie_primi_top_10"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"


    /> 
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now modify adapter as:

```
  public class HorizontalAdapterImageViewTopDieci extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalAdapterImageViewTopDieci.HorizontalViewHolder> 
 {

 private int[] items;

 public HorizontalAdapterImageViewTopDieci(int[] items) {

     this.items = items;

 }

 @Override
 public HorizontalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout_recycler_view_immagini_top_10, parent, false);
     return new HorizontalViewHolder(view);
 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(HorizontalViewHolder holder, int position) {
     holder.image.setImageResource(items[position]);
     holder.titleText.setText("Image"+position);
 }

 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
      return items.length;
 }

 public class HorizontalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     ImageView image;
     TextView titleText;

     public HorizontalViewHolder(View itemView) {
         super(itemView);
         image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_ricette_categorie_primi_top_10);
         titleText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);

     }
 }
  }
```

Comment: You want to set single text for all text in list

Comment: So change code as: holder.titleText.setText("Recipe");

Comment: Yes but is not a static text it changes for each image

Comment: anyway it does not work, neither "Image" or "recipe" are  displayed below my images

Comment: Sir/madam, it's currently working at my end. Can you please update code with latest one after my code updation??

Comment: Yes i have updated , Maybe i need to change the java in ActivityMain?

Comment: Your code is not edited since last 45min..please check again

Comment: Thank you Soo much, its what i proposed to you. Can you please check by changing color of TextView. and it color is not an issue, then comment this line "holder.titleText.setText("Image"+position);" and try it.

Comment: Nothing neither changing color or if I comment the line that you suggested. No one text  is displayed

Comment: May i request you to send me your code on my email id?, i will do and reply you.

Comment: here is my email id, ankitpatidar030@gmail.com. Please send full project as a zip file

Comment: I cant send to you because the project is not my property. Sorry I know that you want to help me :(

Comment: Try to clean the project before running it. The Clean project option is in the Build tab at the top.

Comment: nothing work for him, i don't able to understand what is happening.